# How To Parse a slow-loading webpage with scrapy in combination with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web, dynamic, scrapy

following is what I've tried:

```
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class PdfxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pdf'
    urls = 'https://www.pdfdrive.com/living-in-the-light-a-guide-to-personal-transformation-d10172273.html'

    def start_requests(self):
         yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=self.urls,
            callback=self.parse,
            #wait_time=1000,
            wait_until=EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'alternatives'))
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('a.btn-success').xpath('@href').get())
```

Comment: What’s the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it with requests and BeautifulSoup

Something like this will get you the similar links, and fast.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pdfdrive.com/living-in-the-light-a-guide-to-personal-transformation-d10172273.html'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a', {"class":"ai-similar"})
for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```